# Undine Weaponshaft and Projectiles

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment, racial-traits, improvised-weaponry

Could I load at least 1 projectile (mostly arrows, bolts) into my Undine Weaponshaft longspear and fire it/them by using my *hydraulic push* ability?

Answer (score 1):

No. That's not something *hydraulic push* can do. It can

- knock over a creature
- soak a creature or square
- bull rush a creature or object

Bull rushing does no damage and moves the target one square, plus one square for every 5 points your attack surpasses the CMD. It's not entirely clear what an arrow's CMD might be (it's only defined for creatures), but taking a few liberties and assuming 0 Dex and 0 Str and Diminutive size (much like object AC calculations), the CMD would be -4. If there's a creature in the way of the bull rush target's path, you make another CMB check against that creature's CMD — with a -4 penalty — and push them both the appropriate distance (minus the distance already pushed).

So this would, at most, just waste ammo and push the enemy away with an effective penalty of -4.